Why does an atom become positively charged when it shares its lone pair?
Why does an atom become positively charged when it shares its lone pair?
In NH3, Nitrogen doesn't get positive charge when forming covalent bond with Hydrogens. But why does it get positive charge with it shares with the fourth Hydrogen to form Coordinate bond? Those 2 electrons (1 lone Pair) from valence shell of Nitrogen are being shared by both of them, just like covalent bond.
And moreover, even if Nitrogen is supposed positive charge, it should have +2 charge and not +1 charge since it is taking 2 electrons out of it's valence shell and giving it to Hydrogen.

Adding another hydrogen doesn’t make it positive. Losing an electron makes it positive. If you count electrons in the Lewis structure of the ammonium cation, you will see there are only 8 rather than the 9 valence electrons you would expect from nitrogen (5) and four hydrogens (4).
